# Add private Python package hosted at private package index server as dependency in `pyproject.toml`

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am developing new package `mypackage2` that has a private package `mypackage1` as a dependency. `mypackage1` is hosted on a private package index server (`pypiserver` in this case) and can be installed by:

```
pip install -i http://myprivatepypiserver/simple/ mypackage1`
```

I am trying to list `mypackage1` as a dependency of `mypackage2` in the `pyproject.toml` but am not sure how to set the private `pypiserver` index URL in accordance with PEP 508.

How do I properly add `mypackage1` as a dependency?

`pyproject.toml`

```
[project]
name = "mypackage2"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
    'pandas',
    'mypackage1@http://myprivatepypiserver/simple/',
]
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is not standardized. This depends on which packaging/development tool(s) you are using (Poetry for example or something else).

Comment: I have a `setup.py` in same directory as `pyproject.toml` and use `python -m build` to build.

Comment: Correction, it is up to the installer to select which server(s) to install from. In your case (you do not seem to use Poetry or any kind of similar tool Pipenv(?)), there is nothing to add to `pyproject.toml` inor `setup.py`. What do you use to install? pip?

Comment: I am not sure what `python -m build` uses when installing. When just developing I `pip install` a private requirements.txt with the private index and then pip install the other pypi requirements separately.

Comment: My understanding is that `build` is not relevant here. -- This is my recommendation: In the list of dependencies there should be `mypackage1` (without the `@http://...`). And in the documentation of the library it should be noted where `mypackage1` can be obtained (from which Python package index server, because it is not on PyPI). -- Now when a user wants to install `mypackage2` they will know from the documentation that it depends on `mypackage1` which is not on PyPI but on `myprivatepypiserver`. And this user will be able to configure their installer (`pip` or something else) properly.